# Get list of user-defined templates in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to execute a function for each user-defined template in Meteor.

Example:

```
<template name="settings">
    <p>Settings</p>
</template>
```

Then in some JS file:

```
template_names = ...
_.each(template_names, function(name) {
    Template[name].rendered = defaultRenderingFunction;
});
```

Is there some well-defined way to get the list of user-defined (not system-defined) templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with this solution so far:

```
var template_names = [];
for (var key in Template) {
  if (Template.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // Meteor internal templates begin with _
    if (key.indexOf('_') !== 0) {
      template_names.push(key);
    }
  }
}
```

It will include templates included in other packages.

Comment: why don't you do it the other way around? define a global defaultRenderingFunction() somewhere in your client/lib folder and call it from within your templates' rendered callbacks. This way you would have more fine-grained control over where to run this.

Comment: That's what I did at first, and it works. But later when we add new templates, it will be easy for another developer (or even myself) to forget to assign the function to the new template's `rendered` property. If the approach I've outline here turns out to work, we may build a helper to construct a template that will automatically add this function by default (but then that still requires a developer remember to use that helper!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each(Template, function(template) {
    if(template.startsWith("_")){
        // Assuming user defined templates do not start with a "_"
        return true;
    }
    Template[template].rendered = defaultRenderingFunction;
});
```